# Angular observable property - best practices

Tags: angular

I wonder about the best practices to implement observable properties in Angular 4+.

The documentation shows a solution with `Subject<x>` and `Observeable<x>`: 
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

But all I want is a property in a service which I can bind to several components and end up something like this:

```
  public _foobar: any;

  @Input()
  public set foobar(val: any) {
    this._foobar = val;
    this.foobarChange.emit(val);
  }

  public get foobar(): any {
    return this._foobar;
  }

  @Output()
  public foobarChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

and the bind with `[(ngModel)]="service.foobar"` works great.

Now the question is:

- is this bad practice?
- why? or why it isnt shown in the documentation like this.
- whats better on the subject/observable approach?

Im just confused and sure if I can rely on this.

Kind regards
Gregor

**EDIT:**

Well its even more easy to ignore the getter / setter (I just need it in my specific case) but it works fine without too:

```
@Input() foobar: any;
@Output() foobarChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Answer (score 7):

The best practice to sharing data between parent and child components use [@Input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) and [@Output](https://angular.io/api/core/Output)

When you need to use service for sharing. You need to use [Subject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subject.js~Subject.html) or [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/BehaviorSubject.js~BehaviorSubject.html)

**service example**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private data: BehaviorSubject<MyData> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  getData(): Observable<MyData> {
    return this.data;
  }

  setData(d: MyData): void {
    this.data.next(d);
  }
}
```

**use in component**

```
public data: Observable<MyData>;

constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.data = this.myService.getData();
}
```

**use in template**

```
<div>{{data|async}}</div>
```

Comment: 'get' and 'set' accessor must have the same type.ts(2380)